# HDI: Disable postback on html input box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an input box that I don't want postback to occur on someone striking the enter key

I want the javascript event to take place instead.

```
<input 
type="text" 
id="addressInput" 
onkeydown="inputenter()" 
autopostback="false"/>

    function inputenter() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            seachLocations();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Accept-Enter-Key.aspx

```
<input type="text" id="addressInput" onkeydown="if (window.event.keyCode == 13) 
{
    event.returnValue=false; 
    event.cancel = true;
    searchLocations();
}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Just return false form JS function, add **return false;** at the end of function.

or `<input  type="text"

id="addressInput"

onkeydown ="return (event.keyCode!=13)" 
autopostback="false"/>`

UPDATE:
How about this..?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
 onkeydown="return CallEnterKeyFunc(event.keyCode);"> 
</asp:TextBox>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CallEnterKeyFunc(key) {
        if (key == 13) { //for FF, i think you have to use evt.which
                //enter key press
                seachLocations();
                return false;

            }
            else
                return true;

    }

    function seachLocations() {
       //your code
        alert("hello");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and diligence.  It's still not working.  if 'false' gets returned ONLY it works fine.  When it tries to run another function/method it fails and does the postback. :o(